# Shorewall: logging to custom file

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, shorewall

I am running an [Ubuntu Server 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide) system with a [shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) firewall. Shorewall is essentially a front end to [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/firewall.html), and it is iptables that does the logging via Netfilter (my understanding so far).

My problem is that I can't make sense of the [shorewall docs regarding logging](http://shorewall.net/shorewall_logging.html#Where) to a different destination. This is how far I've come:

- I installed and started `ulogd`
- I defined a variable in `/etc/shorewall/params`: `LOG=NFLOG`
- I changed all occurrences of `info` to `$LOG` in `/etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf`
- I set the log destination in `/etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf`: `LOGFILE=/var/log/shorewall`

This supposedly accomplishes the following: Netfilter logs to the `NFLOG` (successor to `ULOG`) destination, which means Netfilter log messages are handled by `ulogd2`.

**What I don't know, is how I can tell `ulogd2` to write all shorewall messages to my desired log file `/var/log/shorewall`.**

The documentation is rather unclear on this, as [this forum thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=59705) testifies.
This [blog post](http://madjack.wordpress.com/2006/08/28/shorewall-and-ulogd/) I found is equally vague, regarding `ulogd2`'s log redirection.

### In summary:

1. Is my approach for redirecting shorewall log messages to `ulogd2` correct at all?
2. How can I configure `ulogd2` to redirect shorewall's messages to `/var/log/shorewall`?

PS: I am not asking this question on AskUbuntu, because this is equally relevant for other Linux distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu uses rsyslog so you can configure it to filter messages and write them to arbitary log files e.g create a file /etc/rsyslog.d/shorewall.conf

```
:msg, contains, "Shorewall:" /var/log/shorewall
& ~
```

Or if you want to split things out some more

```
:msg, contains, "Shorewall:cust2net:ACCEPT:" /var/log/shorewallc2na.log
& ~

:msg, contains, "Shorewall:" /var/log/shorewall
& ~
```

Which puts all messages containing "Shorewall:cust2net:ACCEPT:" into one log file and any other messages containing "Shorewall" into a different log file.

You need to restart rsyslogd for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to update the `policy` file:

```
#SOURCE     DEST    POLICY      LOG LEVEL   LIMIT:BURST
$FW         net  ACCEPT
net         all     DROP        $LOG
# The FOLLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST
all         all     REJECT      $LOG
```